# Is there a Ember compatible minify and uglify script that runs on command line?

Tags: ember.js

I need to minify and uglify my code from Windows command line. I'm not using Broccoli or Grunt based building process as it is too slow. Also I'm not using ES6 sytax, but old school App.Something style globals.

Comment: There's one built into `ember-cli` that you might be able to extract and use.

Comment: What alternative are you considering either than grunt or brocolli? I've used uglifyjs with grunt.

Comment: Too slow? it takes seconds with broccoli

Comment: I have php script that includes all javascript and templates files on the fly, so it is very fast in development mode. Broccoli has gone faster, but it is still slow for me, I will try again moving to broccoli based environment in few months, currently have to stick with my custom solution.
 
Before going to production I will run a command line build script that precompiles templates and minifies/uglifies everything.